# XSL | Selectively copy only certain elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml document that consist only of `<product>` elements. I would like to copy only those that have:

```
<hotspots>
    <flag type="newproduct" visible="yes"/>
</hotspots>
```

elements inside. I need to do so via xsl.

The example `<product>` looks like this:

```
<product>
    <producer>
    <category>
    <unit>
    <description>
    </description>
    <images>
    </images>
    <parameters>
    </parameters>
    <hotspots>
    </hotspots>
</product>
```

Was thinking it would be a tad easier. I do have xsl looking like that:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/product">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="product/hotspots/flag[@type='newproduct']"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> I have an xml document that consist only of `<product>` elements.

That is not possible. An XML document must also have a single root element. And then your attempt should look something like:

```
<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="product[hotspots/flag/@type='newproduct']"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Sorry, it goes:

'
    <offer>
     <products>
          <product>
          </product>
     </products>
    </offer>
'

Comment: Well, then make it `<xsl:template match="/offer">` and `<xsl:copy-of select="products/product[hotspots/flag/@type='newproduct']"/>`.

Comment: So the final version should look something like this?

`<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/offer">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="products/product[hotspots/flag/@type='newproduct']"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>`

Comment: I don't know. Please don't post code in comments. Edit your question and add a [mcve] showing input and expected output.

Comment: Ok. Thank you and sorry! Will try it out!